# Ubuntu Cuckoo Sandbox installation -cryptography version mismatch

Tags: 18.04, python, encryption, openssl

```
Python 2.7.15rc1
OpenSSL 1.1.0g 
Cuckoo==2.0.6.2

$ cuckoo -d

Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/local/bin/cuckoo", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3105, in <module>

@_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3089, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3118, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 580, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 593, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (cryptography 2.1.4 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('cryptography>=2.2.1'), set(['pyOpenSSL']))
```

I'm unable to fix this issue, I was not able to find anything online, please let me know how to fix this error so that I can run the Cuckoo sandbox. I'm new to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo pip install -U pyopenssl
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** "Should", "Try", "might", ... are symptoms that you're posting a comment. "do", "will", "shall" are symptoms for an answer!  **;-)**  Please [edit] your answer to reflect that (and that you've tested this)